# Application Insights LogInformation not working

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have started to use application insights to log messages from a console application. 
Only critical and errors are being logged. Information or trace are not being logged. Any ideas of why information is excluded?

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // Create the DI container.
        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();


        services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder.AddFilter<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("Category", LogLevel.Information));

        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService("653ac7cb-7563-42fb-ba06-0bd098bcd67c");

        // Build ServiceProvider.
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        var factory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();

        ILogger<Program> logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();

        var telemetryClient = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TelemetryClient>();

        using (telemetryClient.StartOperation<RequestTelemetry>("Firefly.Core.ClientRunner.Worker.exe"))
        {

            logger.LogCritical("Critical A");
            logger.LogDebug("Debug A");
            logger.LogError("Error A");
            logger.LogInformation("Information A", "item 1", "item 2", 4);
            logger.LogTrace("Trace A");
            telemetryClient.Flush();
            Task.Delay(5000).Wait();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Try putting `telemetryClient.Flush(); Task.Delay(5000).Wait();` *after* the using block

Answer (score 2):

Only Warning or above severity logs are captured by default. It looks like you are trying to collect logs of Information and above, but your code below is doing it only for category named "Category".

```
services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder.AddFilter<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>("Category", LogLevel.Information));
```

Replace it with actual category name, or use the following to get from all categories.

```
logging.AddFilter<Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>
                        ("", LogLevel.Information)
```

Comment: This worked for me (in Program.cs Host.ConfigureWebHostDefaults, webBuilder.ConfigureLogging). However it's my understanding this should work via the appsettings.json file, and I can not get that to work. Any insight there?

Comment: Hi!  I added a new answer showing how to do this in appsettings

Answer (score 2):

You can also customize these settings using `appsettings.json`, just add the following but note that the settings must be nested within the `Logging` node.

```
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Debug",
            "System": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Information",
            //you can also define custom behavior by namespace, like if you don't want the thousands of messages you'll get from HttpClient
            "System.Net.Http.HttpClient": "Warning"
        },
        "ApplicationInsights": {
            "LogLevel": {
                "Default": "Debug",
                "System": "Information",
                "Microsoft": "Information",
                //you can also define custom behavior by namespace, like if you don't want the thousands of messages you'll get from HttpClient
                "System.Net.Http.HttpClient": "Warning"
            }
        }
    }
}
```